# setting own Key in Entity while using app engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jpa

I am using eclipse to create a app engine based application where I am also using app engine datastore(using JPA) using endpoints. 
I wrote a test application with help from 
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities
 and it went fine.

Now I want to create an entity where I define my own Key rather than it being automatically assigned by the system. Can someone help me as to what do I need to do that in my Notes.java entity class.  By default the Notes.java like this.

```
package com.bfp.mypackage;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
    public class Note {

      @Id
      private String id;
                  private String emailAddress;
      private String description;
              public Note() {
      }

      public String getId() {
      return id;
      }

      public String getDescription() {
        return description;
      }

      public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
      }

      public void setId(String idIn) {
        this.id = idIn;
      }


      public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
      }

      public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
      this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
      }

             }
```

When I test this code I see the Note entity created in my dev app server admin console with the values(an emailAddress, a dsescription and an ID(I pass timestamp there)) I had supplied. I see two other fields created when I view the entity in admin console. One "Key" and other "Write ops". Now the "Key" field as I understand is the one generated automatically by java. Is there anyway I can set my emailAddress field as the Key? If so then what changes I need to do in above code. That way I can use emailAddress as the unique key for each entity.

Answer (score 0):

You must set your email address as the "Key" name : a key is defined by either an auto-incremented long ID, or a user assigned key name that is unique for an entity kind.

I'm not the most experimented using JPA since I've used mostly JDO and the low level approach, but you might have to use directly the `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key` object instead of a `java.lang.String` attribute...
The low level API method is : 
`KeyFactory.createKey("EntityName", "whatever@domain.com");`